# Eureka service UP, SBA DOWN

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I user SBA as discovery client (spring-boot-admin.version 2.1.5) to Eureka server. I see a registered application UP in Eureka server, but the same is DOWN on SBA.[SBA app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHEPn.png)

These is my application.yml

spring:
  application:
    name: spring-boot-admin-sample-eureka
  profiles:
    active:
      - secure

server:
  port : 8091

## tag::configuration-eureka[]

eureka:   #<1>
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
    statusPageUrlPath: /actuator/info
    health-check-url-path: /actuator/health
    metadata-map:
      startup: ${random.int}    #needed to trigger info and endpoint update after restart
      management.context-path: /monitor-client/actuator
  client:
    registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 5
    registerWithEureka: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/ServicesRepository/eureka

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"  #<2>
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: ALWAYS
  security:
      enabled: false

## end::configuration-eureka[]

---

spring:
  profiles: insecure

---

spring:
  profiles: secure
  security:
    user:
      name: "user"
      password: "password"
eureka:
  instance:
    metadata-map:
      user.name: "user"         #These two are needed so that the server
      user.password: "password" #can access the protected client endpoints

---

spring:
  boot:
    admin:
      client:
        username: user
        password: password
        instance:
          metadata:
            user.name: user
            user.password: password

## Always show details in Health check section

management:
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: "ALWAYS"
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"